# Adding popup info via CRM.help() - doesn't quite work

Tags: custom-fields, extension, javascript

I am trying to add some end user popup help text for some fields in a profile.  I have looked at several examples in core and extensions and have tried to follow them as examples.  I have an extension already loaded where I am (attempting) to manage the code.  I have added the anchor html and "onclick" javascript into the field's pre-help text for the custom field.

The popup works, of sorts.  The popup appears, along with the title supplied in the anchor tag, but the actual content of the popup does not.
    `<a class="helpicon" title="What is this?" href="#" onclick='CRM.help(&quot;What is this?&quot;, {"id":"what-is-this","file":"CRM/Myextension/myextension.hlp"}); return false;'>&nbsp;</a>
 </div>`

The .hlp file has IDs named correctly AFAIK, as what-is-this-title and what-is-this.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I have implemented the [popup help texts in CiviSEPA](https://github.com/Project60/org.project60.sepa/blob/master/templates/CRM/Admin/Form/Setting/SepaSettings.tpl#L57). The main difference here is that the .hlp file extension is omitted, the directory separator in the path are escaped and that I have enclosed the code in `{literal}` `{/literal}`-tags.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I got it working.  It ended up being a combination of using &quote; entities and escaping directories.  I also omitted the .hlp extension but I don't know that it made a difference.  Using tags wouldn't have worked for me since this isn't in a template, it's in submitted data - form help text.